# How do I increase VirtualBox resolution past 800x600 in Linux?

Tags: linux, virtualbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ubuntu on VirtualBox can only show resolution of 800x600 - how to change it?](https://superuser.com/questions/144411/ubuntu-on-virtualbox-can-only-show-resolution-of-800x600-how-to-change-it)

No matter what I do I cannot get the resolution past 800x600. If I am using a Windows install in VirtualBox, I can get it to 1024x768.

What is limiting me from doing this in Linux?

Comment: funny this is the duplicate when it was created 2 years prior..

Comment: look here http://askubuntu.com/a/489948/287960

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Have you installed the VirtualBox Guest Additions on your guest yet? If so, then the size of the guest should reflect the size of your VirtualBox window, so if you maximise the latter, your guest should resize its display accordingly.

You may also need to activate VirtualBox's Auto-resize Guest Display option (Host-G is a hot key for that).

Comment: http://helpdeskgeek.com/linux-tips/install-virtualbox-guest-additions-in-ubuntu/ may be of use if you're having trouble installing guest additions.

Answer (score 8):

If installing guest additions does not solve the problem for you try the following:

`sudo apt-get install virtualbox-ose-guest-x11`

And some more info on the problem here: http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=33645&start=0

Comment: That one actually have worked form me. +1

Comment: Worked for me (remember to reboot). Alternatively see http://helpdeskgeek.com/linux-tips/install-virtualbox-guest-additions-in-ubuntu/

Comment: +1 Worked for Gentoo host and Ubuntu 14.04 guest. The package name seems to have changed to `virtualbox-guest-x11`