# Increase resolution for debian guest in virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, debian, resolution, guest-additions

I have a windows 7 host and a debian 8 guest. I already installed

```
virtualbox-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-x11 virtualbox-guest-dkms
```

as described in https://askubuntu.com/questions/3205/higher-screen-resolution-in-virtualbox. Before installing these packages I was able to select a maximum of 1024*768. After installation 1600*1200 was possible. But I simply want to use 1920*1080 fullscreen on my display.

Pressing Host-G is not possible. I seams this combination is deactivated.
[How do I increase VirtualBox resolution past 800x600 in Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/239768/how-do-i-increase-virtualbox-resolution-past-800x600-in-linux)

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a solution for that in the meanwhile.

There are two descriptions that show how this works:

1st:
[How to adjust the screen resolution in Debian?](https://superuser.com/questions/716795/how-to-adjust-the-screen-resolution-in-debian)

2nd:
http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=78330#p429581

In short:

```
$ cvt 1920 1080 60
# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
$ xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
$ xrandr --addmode VBOX0 "1920x1080_60.00"
$ xrandr --output VBOX0 --mode 1920x1080_60.00
```

After execution these commands automatically the new resolution appears. Additionally these commands must be executed after each start of the operating system.

In the meantime I wrote a blog post about that topic: http://www.robert-franz.com/2015/06/28/adding-new-resolution-to-the-x-window-server/

Comment: This works to me, with same config but changing VBOX0 by VGA-0. Thanks !!

Comment: This worked for me but I had to check settings --> display to find the screen name which was `Virtual1` instead of `VBOX0` in my case

Answer (score 8):

A straightforward way of achieving that would be to change the specific configuration in the grub2 bootloader directly:

1. Find out the resolutions supported by your debian guest

   - Reboot debian and keep pressing `c` until you see the grub console.
   - Press `vbeinfo` and hit enter. It will give you a list of supported resolutions.
2. Edit `/etc/grub.d/00_header`

   - Replace `auto`in the line `if [ "x${GRUB_GFXMODE}" = "x" ] ; then GRUB_GFXMODE=auto ; fi` with the new resolution. e.g.: `if [ "x${GRUB_GFXMODE}" = "x" ] ; then GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1080 ; fi`
   - Right underneath, make a copy of the line edited and replace `MODE` with `PAYLOAD`. e.g.: `if [ "x${GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD}" = "x" ] ; then GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD=1920x1080 ; fi`
   - Further below, you'll find the following line: `set gfxmode=${GRUB_GFXMODE}`. Add the following line below it: `set gfxpayload=${GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD}`
3. Reload grub2 configurations by running the command `update-grub2` and rebooting afterwards `reboot`

[Note]
I've seen many examples in which the default line `#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480` in the file `/etc/defaul/grub` in uncommented. It was proven to be unnecessary for me but in case you need it, remember to `update-grub2` after you've uncommented it.

Comment: Worked great, even with steps 2.2 and 2.3 omitted :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I know this question realtes to different versions but it might be usefull for someone that has installed the latest version of VirtualBox (5.2)

My setup:

- VirtualBox 5.2.0 r118431
- Host OS: Windows 10
- Guest OS: Linux Debian 9.2.1 with XFCE
- Guest Additions ISO: VBoxGuestAdditions_5.2.1-118447 (please note that this is not the ISO you get with the default installer, there is a note on virtualbox site to download a newer version)

The following commands must be run in super user mode on guest OS rebooted:

```
mkdir -p /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/include/drm

touch /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/include/drm/drm_rect.h
```

The `VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` must be executed again, and then guest OS need a reboot

There is also a newer Guest Additions ISO in the development downloads which should fix this problem [Virtualbox Test builds](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Testbuilds)

Credits:

- [Ticket #17203](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/17203)
- [vboxvideo build is skipped, Debian 9.2, GA 5.2.1-r118447](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=85132)

Answer (score 1):

Check the screen size in Windows:

> Control panel -> Sound & Hardware -> Screen

Y the left of the windows select `Adjust resolution`, and you can see what is the actual resolution of the host screen, use that in your Ubuntu/Debian. In Debian go to `Settings -> Displays`, choose the display and adjust the resolutions, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a Debian 10 image in VirtualBox under Windows 10, and installed Debian with the default GUI.

I found that within the GUI, I was able to select a resolution directly (eg. 1920x1440 in my case, my host machine's max res), avoiding having to wrangle with the CLI.

> Settings (app) -> Devices -> Displays -> Resolution

Choosing a resolution caused the VM to assume the selected screen size and the VirtualBox window resized appropriately.

Comment: I did try the top-voted solution (including using `XWAYLAND0` as the display name, as reported by `xrandr` on my machine) and failed, so I was pleasantly surprised to find the GUI approach worked seamlessly.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation or code instead of using comments as you did.

Comment: @help-info.de I've adjusted the answer slightly, emphasizing the GUI path to achieve this. I specifically added this answer to ensure searchers who assume that the CLI is required (eg. me, some comfort with Linux servers, but not desktop) also realize that a straight-forward GUI solution is also available.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that although the 1920x1080 resolution was available and enabled in the VB menu, selecting it didn't change it.

I've tried the `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-x11 virtualbox-guest-dkms`, and the suggestion to correct the Grub-file above, but what seemed to do the trick, was to upgrade Virtualbox to 5.1.20 and install the corresponding version of the guestadditions.