# VirtualBox resolution maxed at 1024x768 after Guest Additions

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

So I've seen several posts say that installing Guest Additions for VirtualBox 4 running Ubuntu (host is Windows 7) should allow you to set a resolution higher than 800x600. There is also [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/144411/ubuntu-on-virtualbox-can-only-show-resolution-of-800x600-how-do-i-change-it) on SuperUser, but the last comment says its deprecated for VB4.

I have installed guest additions, but the max resolution is still 1024x768. I want to up it to at least 1280x1024. I have set the display memory for the box at the max of 128.

Is this just as good as it gets, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 7):

Make sure to turn off the VM.

Then go to VirtualBox Manager > File > Preferences > Display, click the Maximum Guest Screen Size dropdown and make sure to select either None or Auto (whichever works best).

[image: A picture says it all]

Comment: This option doesn't seem to exist in the most recent version of VirtualBox

Comment: This fixed my problem, I did not even know this setting existed :-) thank you

Comment: @BrianLeishman, it does for me using https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/openSUSE:/Factory/standard/x86_64/virtualbox-7.0.12-2.3.x86_64.rpm on cpe:/o:opensuse:tumbleweed:20240109. However, chaning it from Automatic to None still didn't allow me to use https://sourceforge.net/projects/blissos-x86/files/Official/BlissOS15/Gapps/Generic/Bliss-v15.8.6-x86_64-OFFICIAL-gapps-20230703.iso on any resolution greater than 1024x768. It could be, per https://superuser.com/a/1340791/904401, because of https://github.com/BlissRoms-x86/support/issues/35#issuecomment-1889652945.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me in the end was to increase the video RAM size for the virtual machine from the default of 16MB to 128MB (maximum guest screen size: none). With 16MB there was no way I could make it work (at the time of this post), although it worked fine previously for quite some months.

I have to mention that I'm running Kali instead of Ubuntu in the guest (host is Windows 10), but since they're both debian-based this still might apply for some people.

Comment: Increasing video RAM was the secret step for me (VirtualBox w/ Ubuntu, on a Win10 host).

Answer (score 0):

VirtualBox is *supposed* to resize the guest display to the size of the VirtualBox window on the host (if you select the relevant option). But unfortunately it's finicky.

Try resizing the window and waiting a few seconds. Repeat a few times if necessary. If that doesn't resize the guest, try rebooting the guest.

Answer (score 0):

Funny, I accidentally ran Windows 10 as Type: Linux system in settings, this made windows not to detect any VB devices and resolution was 1024

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?p=329477#p329477 and https://superuser.com/a/1210957/904401 demonstrate, changing:

1. *File*
2. *Preferences*
3. *Display*
4. *Maximum Guest Screen Size*

from *Automatic* to *None* should provide this capability. However, as [VirtualBox resolution maxed at 1024x768 after Guest Additions](https://superuser.com/questions/453679/virtualbox-resolution-maxed-at-1024x768-after-guest-additions#comment2875822_1210957) explains, it still didn't allow me to use https://sourceforge.net/projects/blissos-x86/files/Official/BlissOS15/Gapps/Generic/Bliss-v15.8.6-x86_64-OFFICIAL-gapps-20230703.iso on any resolution greater than 1024 by 768 pixels.

I consequently expect, as https://superuser.com/a/1340791/904401 and https://github.com/BlissRoms-x86/support/issues/35#issuecomment-1889652945 together demonstrate, that hardware acceleration must be enabled by the host and client OS, and it must be functional.