# Ubuntu on Virtualbox screen is too small, can't change resolution

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, resolution

I'm installing Ubuntu on Virtual Box but the screen was too tiny to do anything.

I used the Scale to 200% option at the bottom toolbar of VirtualBox but when I finally got Ubuntu setup and ready to go, I went to change the resolution in displays but I'm unable to do so. The screen is too cut off and I can't see any of the resolution options thus I have no way of changing it.

I tried using `xrandr` on the command line and it helped fit everything in the window except when I did full screen I had a tiny window and the rest of the full screen window was black. I was able to see the resolution options though but then when I went ahead and changed the resolution I was unable to confirm the new resolution and it reverted back to the original issue where the screen is cut off and I can't see the resolution options

Answer (score 19):

In order to make the screen bigger, follow the next steps.

1. Start the VM
2. Click in Devices > Insert Guest Additions CD image...

[image: VirtualBox Devices Insert Guest Additions CD image...]

3. You'll see a CD icon in your Favorites (left side). Double click on it

[image: CD icon in Ubuntu]

4. Here's what you'll see. In the top right there's a button saying "Run Software". Click on it.

[image: Inside of Ubuntu's CD icon]

5. Then, without touching anything else, once the software finished running the screen goes bigger.

[image: VirtualBox screen big yey]

**Note**: once you power off the VM and start it again, don't be scared if it starts again with small screen because before you're ready to use it, the screen will be big again without you needing to touch anything. Also, you'll still see the CD; feel free to right click on it and Eject it.

[image: Finally]

Comment: The main issue was during installation. Not after.

Comment: Clicking Run Software didn't do anything. Opening that same directory in the terminal and running `./autorun.sh` and then rebooting did the trick*. Before all of this though I ran `sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential dkms` because I saw it in a YouTube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zdkl16oAS1k). Not sure what it does. Only problem now is if I make the window too big, the display goes black.

Comment: Update, this fixes my black screen issue: https://superuser.com/a/1621132/485008 Also, holding shift while resizing the window preserves the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 8):

IT worked for me.

If you created the Ubuntu VM with 6.0.0, you need to shut down the VM, go to the VM Settings » Display » Screen » Graphics Controller = VBoxVGA.

Comment: THIS was the fix. VMVGA did not work.

Comment: Did not work for me on VirtualBox 6.1. The [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1557176/573158) below did.

Comment: Tried this method with Ubuntu 22.04 on VirtualBox 7.0.8 / Windows 10. It certainly helps for the installation session, but after that Ubuntu fails to reboot without reverting the setting to VMVGA.

Comment: *VMSVGA. Sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 4):

All terribly wrong answers.

During first boot from live CD, you first need to exit the installation screen. You can select "Try Ubuntu" button.

Then just right-click the desktop, select Display Settings, and choose a different resolution.

Then run the installer. I did have to re-select the resolution again during the installer for some reason.

The same issue occurs with PopOS install. With PopOS right-click the application icon and choose Quit. Then same as above to change resolution. Mint doesn't seem as bad as the default resolution seems to be larger.

Once the OS is installed you do want to install Guest Additions. If you install Guest Additions on live CD it won't be available after you install so you will just have to install it again.

Comment: You are so right. No need to install the Guest Additions.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have installed Ubuntu 22 on VirtualBox 7.0 on Mac

1. In VirtualBox settings

   1. Settings > System > Motherboard: turn up base memory
   2. Settings > System > Processor: turn up processors
   3. Settings > Display > Screen: turn up video memory to max
2. Launch VM

   1. (on menu bar) Devices > Insert Guest Additions CD image...
   2. (bottom left apps) Show Application > (search) Settings
   3. In Setting > [Language and Region](https://askubuntu.com/a/1436448), change it to English (United Kingdom)
   4. (bottom left apps) Show Application > (search) Terminal
   5. [Make your user a sudoer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1440054)

```bash
su -
usermod -a -G sudo <your username>
```

3. Relaunch VM

   1. In terminal, run `findmnt` check the last line looks something like `/media/<your username>/VBox_GAs_7.0.6 ...`
   2. In terminal, run `sudo /media/<your username>/VBox_GAs_7.0.6/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`
4. Relaunch VM. Now you can manage your screen size with this icon in the bottom right menu bar.
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

Install the Guest Box Additions inside the Ubuntu machine. Read down in section 4.1 about resizing the guest window

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html

I have Ubuntu 18 running as a guest inside VMware Workstation with VMware Tools installed and the guest machine fills the VMware Window